# How to add drop shadow to the current element in a tab menu?

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I've got a tabbed menu that looks something like this:

[image: My tabbed menu]

The html for it is simple:

```
 <div id="menuContainer">
    <ul id="menu" class="undecorated ">
        <li id="menuHome"><%= Html.ActionLink<HomeController>(c=>c.Index(), "Home") %> </li>
        <li id="menuAbout"><%= Html.ActionLink<UsergroupController>(c=>c.About(), "About") %> </li>
        <li id="menuArchives"><%= Html.ActionLink<UsergroupController>(c=>c.Archives(), "Archives") %> </li>
        <li id="menuLinks"><%= Html.ActionLink<UsergroupController>(c=>c.Links(), "Links") %> </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="menuBar" class="container">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

And the JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').corner();
    $('ul#menu li').corner('30px top');
});
```

and on each page something like:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuHome').addClass('current')
 })
```

I would like to indicate the "current" tab with a drop shadow behind it.  I am thinking I would do this by

1. Create a shadow 'li' with $('.current').after('&nbsp
  ')
2. Use CSS to set the shadow color and round the top right corner with jquery
3. Shift it over with CSS position: relative; top: 5px; left: -5px;

The problem that I am having is that the shadow appears on top of the element to the left. Setting its z-index low makes it disappear altogether for some reason.  How do I make it appear behind the previous list-item?

Alternatively, what's a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a link to a live example? We need to see the CSS to solve the issue.

Comment: Not live anywhere but the CSS is exactly what you would expect. Here it is http://codepaste.net/aphafw

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to consider using the CSS box-shadow technique.  Mozilla and Webkit have implemented it, and box-shadow is in the CSS3 specs so someday it should be widely adopted.  There is also a box-shadow filter for IE, but I don't know if it displays a very good look shadow.  However, if you used this technique, it would be much more efficient.  Although it wouldn't work in EVERY browser, it would give a similar effect for most of your users.

Here's a link to some more details about it: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Here's some information on IE filters (very under-utilized):http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml

If you are looking for a shadow around the entire image, consider using the IE glow filter instead of the dropshadow.

Here's some sample CSS to work with if you want to try this technique.

```
div#someID {
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: #888 10px 10px 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #888 10px 10px 5px;
FILTER: DropShadow(Color=#888, OffX=5, OffY=-3, Positive=1);
}
```

Comment: box-shadow is interesting but it doesn't work in browsers that most people use. It works in chrome but still is a problem when using lists.  If I wanted for example to add a shadow to each tab it would still overlap the next element.

Answer (score 1):

Apply this style to the current tab (not shadow):

```
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

And this to the shadow

```
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the way `.corner();` works is by drawing hundreds of 1px divs that are the same color as what's behind them. At the very least, the shadow needs to be `.corner()`ed first. If this still doesn't work, then in fact `.corner()` just takes the background color (white).

Comment: Hmm...I was initially tryin this without the cornering and still having problems

Comment: Not live anywhere but the CSS is exactly what you would expect. Here it is http://codepaste.net/aphafw

Comment: Are you saying that my idea should work or is my theory wrong? I've never tried it before

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with this and ended up adding the following (note: I set Archives to current to see it better)

CSS

```
.shadow {
 background-color: #333;
 border-color: #333;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0.7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuArchives').addClass('current');
    $('#menu').after('<div class="shadow"></div>');
    var c = $('.current');
    var widthoffset = 50;
    var heightoffset = 20;
    var topoffset = -4;
    var leftoffset = -2;

    $('.shadow').css({
     width : c.width() + widthoffset + 'px',
     height : c.height() + heightoffset + 'px',
     top : c.offset().top + topoffset + 'px',
     left : c.offset().left + leftoffset + 'px'
    }).corner('30px top');
 })
```

You can mess around with the variables a bit to get the shadow where you want it :P

Edit: It doesn't appear to work in IE, but then a few other parts are off as well... I'll look at it some more
Edit2: Ok, I got it to work in IE, but it's obvious now that the corners are made by a bunch of div's and the background doesn't match up - it looks fine in FF and Chrome