# Hide Section of a Box Shadow

Tags: css

Disclaimer: I have already seen the following questions and their solutions did not apply to me even though they are very similar situations:

- [Creating a CSS3 box-shadow on all sides but one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429605/css3-box-shadow-all-sides-but-one)
- [How to add drop shadow to the current element in a tab menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483261/how-to-add-drop-shadow-to-the-current-element-in-a-tab-menu)
- [CSS shadows on 3 sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253868/css-shadows-on-3-sides#253915)

Simply put, I am trying to add a `-moz-box-shadow` of `0 0 10px` to the `.current_page_item` class that is applied to the currently active tab in the tab navigation at the top of [my website](http://www.blaenkdenum.com). The website does not yet include the actual box-shadow or any of these changes, I have only been playing with these modifications in firebug for now before I actually publish them. Naturally this causes the shadow to appear on all sides, and so the bottom edge's shadow overlaps into the `.content` div which stores all of the blog's actual content, i.e. posts.

Based on what I have seen so far, it seems like I should set the `z-index` of something, not sure what (*I have tried `ul.menu`*) to something lower and the `z-index` of the `.content` div to something higher, but this seems to have no effect.

I am just wondering if this is normal behavior and if not, if someone could help me out with this situation.

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

**EDIT**: I put `box-shadow` in the post earlier, but I meant the respective specific directives, such as `-moz-box-shadow`. That was not the problem I was having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add `overflow:hidden` on the `ul.menu` as honeybuzzer mentions, but since that would also cut-off the top shadow you should add some `padding-top` to the `ul.menu` as well..

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden` on `ul.menu` seems to get rid of the bottom shadow.

Answer (score 0):

`clip-path` is now (2020) an excellent solution for hiding specific box-shadow edges if you're wanting the box-shadow to be cut off "clean" like this:

```css
.shadow-element {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    clip-path: inset(0px -15px 0px 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow-element"></div>
```

Simply apply the following CSS to the element in question:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 Xpx [hex/rgba]; /* note 0 offset values */
clip-path: inset(Apx Bpx Cpx Dpx);
```

Where:

- `Apx` sets the shadow visibility for the top edge
- `Bpx` right
- `Cpx` bottom
- `Dpx` left

Enter a value of 0 for any edges where the shadow should be hidden and a negative value (the same as the box-shadow blur radius - `Xpx`) to any edges where the shadow should be displayed.

This solution removes the need to apply styling to a parent element, which gives more flexibility.