# How can I partially remove a segment of a box shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, box-shadow

I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS/Javascript. I've been using what I learned in class to make changes to my Tumblr theme, but I noticed that when I use the box shadow option that it still draws where a segment of the box it's surrounding has been removed. Here's a picture of what I mean in case I haven't described it well enough:
[Box Shadow Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orcvb.png)

I'm fairly certain I won't have access to all of the Javascript, but some of it is written directly in the HTML file.

I saw this question [Hide Section of a Box Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017315/hide-section-of-a-box-shadow), but it was posted 6 years ago and the website does not seem to have the same layout described in the question anymore so I'm not sure if that solution would work.

Basically, what I need is to cut the box shadow at the same time the hole is cut out of the corner of div to make room for the avatar. Either that, or at least make the avatar render after the box shadow to minimize the problem.

Comment: It's very hard to tell from that picture what the problem is. Do you have another picture?

Comment: I had to increase the zoom in my browser a lot just to get the picture as clear as it is. I couldn't do anything more except outline where the problem is. The problem is that the box shadow renders where the box should be even though the portion of the box is removed.

Comment: Maybe zoom out? Is it the grey section that has a shadow? The circle? Which direction is the shadow going in?

Comment: For the sake of the screenshot you could make the shadow darker, or a more obvious color. Or include the essential code in your question as a "snippet"